# Copy file and if exist create new extension

Tags: c#, file, copy

I have a problem, i am trying to write a program that will copy a  file with the same name from A to B   and i want to change the exension from bk2 to bk3,4,5,6,7 or just rename the filename so the program can copy the file even if the same name allready exist.

I am very beginner in C# everything is dificult now.

Below the code

```
enter code here


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //path of file
    string pathToOriginalFile = @"D:\C#\LOGS_PROG\SystemLog.bk2";
    string extension = ".bk2";


    //duplicate file path 
    string PathForDuplicateFile = @"D:\C#\Backup\Systemlog";

    //provide source and destination file paths
    File.Copy(pathToOriginalFile, PathForDuplicateFile + extension);

   

}
```

}

Comment: [`Path.ChangeExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.changeextension?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 1):

There is few tips.
You can use System.IO.Path.

- path of file

  ```
       string pathToOriginalFile = @"D:\C#\LOGS_PROG\SystemLog.bk2";
  ```
- Where the file is located (D:\C#\LOGS_PROG) be careful, there is no \ at the end

  ```
       string where = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToOriginalFile);
  ```
- THe name of the wile without its extension (SystemLog)

  ```
       string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pathToOriginalFile);
  ```
- its extension (.bk2)

  ```
       string extension = Path.GetExtension(pathToOriginalFile);
  ```
- The name and the extension (SystemLog.bk2)

  ```
       string nameAndExtension = Path.GetFileName(pathToOriginalFile);
  ```

Now, if your purpose is to duplicate the file :

```
 //path of file
 string pathToOriginalFile = @"D:\C#\LOGS_PROG\SystemLog.bk2";

 for (int i = 1; ; ++i)
 {
      // For example : D:\C#\LOGS_PROG\SystemLog (9).bk2 if there is the original + 8 copy
      string pathToNewFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToOriginalFile), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pathToOriginalFile) + " (" + i + ")" + Path.GetExtension(pathToOriginalFile));

      if (!File.Exists(pathToNewFile))
      {
           File.Copy(pathToOriginalFile, pathToNewFile);
           break;
      }
 }
```

I separated the structure so you can see how it is built but you can use already known variables.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //path of file
        string pathToOriginalFile = @"D:\C#\LOGS_PROG\SystemLog.bk2";
        string extension = ".bk2";
        //duplicate file path 
        string PathForDuplicateFile = @"D:\C#\Backup\Systemlog";

        //rename fileName if Exists
        FixFileName(ref PathForDuplicateFile, extension);

        //provide source and destination file paths
        File.Copy(pathToOriginalFile, PathForDuplicateFile + extension);
    }

    static void FixFileName(ref string PathForDuplicateFile, string extention)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            i++;
            if (File.Exists(PathForDuplicateFile + extention))
                PathForDuplicateFile += i;
            else
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! this is changing name of the file but i will change my program to look after the name not after the extension. I spent  today 6h  and nothing. Thank you!!

Comment: Please explain with an example

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved.

The program copy the file and if the file exist it renames the extension.

Winndow runs it every day and so i got my autobackup

Thakns for the help!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //path of file
    string pathToOriginalFile = @"C:\Desktop\c#\Logging\Systemlog.bk66";


    //duplicate file path 
    string PathForDuplicateFile = @"C:\\Desktop\c#\Systemlog";

    //rename fileName if Exists
    FixFileName(ref PathForDuplicateFile, ".bk");

    if (File.ReadAllText(pathToOriginalFile).Length > 2000)
    {

        File.Copy(pathToOriginalFile, PathForDuplicateFile);

    }
      else
    {
      

    }
    //provide source and destination file paths
   
}

static void FixFileName(ref string PathForDuplicateFile, string extention)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        i++;
        if (File.Exists(PathForDuplicateFile + extention))
           extention += i;
        else
            break;
    }
    PathForDuplicateFile += extention;
}
```

}